# force.com site set fixed language (don't translate standard labels)

Tags: force.com, translation

I have a force.com site, which uses a bunch of fixed (English) text, but also some standard labels, e.g.

```
<apex:outputField id="extension" value="{!user.extension}"/>
```

Depending on the users browser settings (I'm guessing e.g. the content language preference in Firefox), users see translated versions of these labels.

I don't want to translate all of my site, so I'm looking for a way to stop salesforce from showing translated labels. I think all of these may work (I haven't tested them all), but they require a bunch of manual work, that I also need to remember to do on each label, page, ... I add in the future:

- Manually add the English label to each apex:outputField, apex:inputField etc, and hope I don't use anything standard that I cannot touch (or override it all).
- for all my pages (and hope I don't have any standard pages I didn't override)

I'm looking for a better way, preferably one that will say for the entire site: 'salesforce please display English labels only'. Something in the site Template maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my idea that the language is detected from the browser is wrong: it is set in the users settings. By not changing the language setting for a user (and not allowing users to do so themselves), they will see only English.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Translation Workbench` is activated in your org. If you want to force only English, you can disable it by going to  `Setup --> Translation Workbench --> Translation Settings` then disable it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, the translation workbench is not enabled (going to that page only gives me the option to enable it).